# Segmentation fault apt-get

Tags: apt

I have Debian Jessie installed and needed to reinstall Apache. When I typed

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

I managed to remove this package. However, any subsequent commands to apt-get produce a segmentation fault:

```
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libonig2 libperl4-corelibs-perl libqdbm14 lsof php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common
  php5-json php5-readline
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 134 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Segmentation fault
/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: 6: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: BEGIN: not found
/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: 1: eval: qq{: not found
/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: 8: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: use: not found
/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: 9: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: use: not found
/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: 10: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Setting up php5-common (5.6.36+dfsg-0+deb8u1) ...
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing package php5-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cli:
 php5-cli depends on php5-common (= 5.6.36+dfsg-0+deb8u1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-cgi:
 php5-cgi depends on php5-common (= 5.6.36+dfsg-0+deb8u1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.
 php5-cgi depends on php5-cli; however:
  Package php5-cli is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5-cgi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5-readline:
 php5-readline depends on phpapi-20131226; however:
  Package phpapi-20131226 is not installed.
  Package php5-common which provides phpapi-20131226 is not configured yet.
 php5-readline depends on php5-common (= 5.6.36+dfsg-0+deb8u1); however:
  Package php5-common is not configured yet.
 php5-readline depends on php5-cli (= 5.6.36+dfsg-0+deb8u1); however:
  Package php5-cli is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php5-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-common
 php5-cli
 php5-cgi
 php5-readline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```